# batch, Create specific folders from specific multiple files, and then move specific multiple files into specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have problem I have some files

07-01.jpg 07-02.jpg until 07-48.jpg

08-01.jpg 08-02.jpg until 08-48.jpg

....

37-01.jpg 37-02.jpg 37-03.jpg until37-48.jpg

I want to create folder 07, 08.... ,37 and then move multiple files 07-01.jpg, 07-02.jpg, 07-03.jpg into folder 07 ;

08-01.jpg, 08-02.jpg, 08-03.jpg into folder 08 ;

......

37-01.jpg, 37-02.jpg, 37-03.jpg into folder 37 etc

can i get any batch script for solving this problem ?

thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? Post some code. We're not here to give you a script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all you should have done some more research, I personally know other questions lie this. Secondly, you should also show the scrit you have so far, so that we can improve it. Try this soloution, if it doesn't work, comment me the error message.

#### Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Rem dont include the last backslash below
set topath="C:\users\...[path to parent directory]"
pushd %topath%

for /r %%f in (*.jpg) do (
Rem Remove the below line and the correspoonding bracket to make this include sub directories
if !topath! equ "%%~ff" (
for /f "delims=_" %%n in ("%%~f") do (
if not exist %%n md %%n
move %%f %%n
)))
```

That should work fine, and if it doesn't, I can make another code to do it manually with `for /l` loops based on the figures you gave me.

#### Manual Script

Heres a specifc soloution:

```
@echo off
pushd D:\case

for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do (
md 0%%a
for /l %%b in (1,1,9) do (
if exist 0%%a_0%%b.jpg (
move 0%%a_0%%b.jpg 0%%a
)))

for /l %%a in (10,1,37) do (
md %%a
for /l %%b in (10,1,48) do (
if exist %%a_%%b.jpg (
move %%a_%%b.jpg %%a
)))
popd
```

That **has** to work. If neither work then please run this in Command prompt so you can give me an error message to work with.
Mona

Comment: it doestn't work, actually my file's name is using "_" not "-", so it is 07_01.jpg etc  
thank for your help

Comment: sorry if my current files is in D:\case , do i have to change C:\users\...[path to parent directory] into D:\case ?

Comment: @user257182 Check my edit it, I've built a specific soloution.